# sqlite self join with where clause

Tags: sqlite, join, self-join

I have a table that consists of names, points, and years.  I need a command to return all the names for a specific year even if the name isn't included in that year.  Example

```
Name        Points    Year
-------    ------- 
tom           8       2011
jim           45      2011
jerry         25      2011
zack         124      2011
jeff          45      2011
tom           62      2012
jim          214      2012
jerry         13      2012
zack          32      2012
arnold         4      2012




Name        Points    Year
-------    ------- 
tom           8       2011
jim           45      2011
jerry         25      2011
zack         124      2011
jeff          45      2011
arnold       NULL     NULL
```

I figured this would be easy but I am struggling to make it work.

Comment: What does "names for a specific year" mean? What does "name isn't included in that year" mean? What are those two tables? We can guess but please explain more clearly. How can you expect to express yourself in SQL when you can't express yourself clearly in natural language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your explanation, I'm thinking you <strike>need</strike> could use something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    N.`Name`,
    D.`Points`,
    Y.`Year`
FROM
    `MyData` Y
LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT `Name` FROM `MyData`) N ON 1=1
LEFT JOIN `MyData` D 
    ON  D.`Year` = Y.`Year` 
    AND D.`Name` = N.`Name`
ORDER BY 
    Y.`Year`
```

While It's not pretty, It does seem to work as intended:

[image]